# Doctrine 2 STI and CTI usage

Tags: php

I read a article http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

In my mind STI and CTI are great ideas. Are this strategies popular and 
recommended nowadays or I should omit it?
I would like to lean my simple project on CTI.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is popular, but I do believe that it is a pattern that still is up-to-date.